# Debian 11 - wrong calendar language

Tags: debian

I installed Debian 11 Gnome. Everything is Ok, except for the language in the Calendar (at top middle of screen).

In Settings > Region and Language, **Language** is `English` and **Formats** is set to `United States`. However, my timezone is `+07 (Bangkok, Thailand)` and I suspect because of this my calendar uses Thai language.

How can I fix this so that English language is used?
[image]

**Update**

The `locale` command outputs the following:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=th_TH.UTF-8
LC_TIME=th_TH.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=th_TH.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=th_TH.UTF-8
LC_NAME=th_TH.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=th_TH.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=th_TH.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=th_TH.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=th_TH.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Could you check your locale settings? What is the output of the  `locale` command from a terminal prompt?

Comment: @FelixJN I updated my question with output of `locale`

Comment: How can I update these values with correct ones?

Answer (score 1):

Locales may be set in various positions. The default values are set in `/etc/default/locale`, some older versions use `/etc/environment`. Alternatively on may set it in the `.profile`, too.

Assuming you are the only user on your system, I'd suggest using `/etc/defaul/locale`. Date is managed with the `LC_TIME`-value, i.e. adapt the value to

```
 LC_TIME="en_US.UTF8"
```

(quotes optional). You may need to reload your profile - simplest by a relogin.

Comment: Thanks for this. I updated `LC_TIME` value and restarted machine. The login screen date/time is now in English. As soon as I logged in the calendar changed to Thai language. When I run `locale` command it shows the old value of `LC_TIME=th_TH.UTF-8`. However, when I open the `/etc/default/locale` it shows my updated value of `LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: Looks like something is overriding it..

Comment: I changed every single entry in `/etc/default/locale` to equal `en_US.UTF-8`, but after logging in the `locale` command still shows `th_TH.UTF-8`.

Comment: I think it is gnome:  if `gsettings get org.gnome.system.locale region` returns the Thai locale, set it to US via `gsettings set org.gnome.system.locale region "en_US.UTF-8"` .

Comment: Haven't tried to look at `gsettings` yet. In `/etc/locale.gen` I removed the Thai locale (left only en_US), ran `locale-gen`. After re-login language seems to be correct. But now terminal doesn't start, sigh..

Comment: It was getting too painful, I reinstalled the system. During install I chose New York / US as my timezone. After the install, I updated my timezone and things are working fine :)